# Encoding a list of frequencies as WAV audio

Tags: python, python-3.x, serialization, audio, signal-processing

This code gets a list of signals with predefined frequency from **struc.num**

I need to encode it to wave format, so i use this code. This works, but i dont sure it is a correct decision to encode like this in python. Is there any ways to do it better?

```
def compiler():
    import out
    print("Loaded out.py")
    print("Compiling...")
    lst = list(my_code(out.code))
    print("Compiled!")
    print("Linking...")

    print("Bytes len: ", len(lst), " = ", blen * len(lst))

    music = wave.open('out.wav', 'w')
    music.setparams((2, 1, freq, 0, 'NONE', 'not compressed'))

    for i in lst:
        if (i == "0"):
            packed_value = wave.struct.pack('h', 0)
            for _ in range(100):
                music.writeframes(packed_value)
            continue

        key = i[0:i.find("(")]
        frame = Syntax.struc.num[int(key)]

        duration = 0.05
        samplerate = freq  # Hz
        samples = duration * samplerate
        frequency = frame #Hz
        period = samplerate / float(frequency)  # in sample points
        omega = N.pi * 2 / period

        xaxis = N.arange(int(period), dtype=N.float) * omega
        ydata = 16384 * N.sin(xaxis)

        signal = N.resize(ydata, 400) # 2-й параметр - скорость

        ssignal = b''
        for i in range(len(signal)):
            ssignal += wave.struct.pack('h', int(signal[i]))  # transform to binary

        music.writeframes(signal)

        #packed_value = wave.struct.pack('h', frame)
        #for _ in range(blen):
        #    music.writeframes(packed_value)
    music.close()

print("Linked to out.wav!")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is hard to tell without knowing how `lst` is structured, but here is what I can say from what you have shown:

1. It is safer and cleaner to open files with the `with` syntax, since it will safely close the file no matter what happens.
2. It is better to do imports at the top of a module, rather than in a function.
3. It is a convention to use ALL CAPS for module-level constants, which you appear to have several of here.  This makes it easier to keep track of what is module-level and what isn't.
4. You re-define certain constants every time through the loop.  It is clearer and faster to define them once outside the loop.
5. It is a convention to import numpy as `np`, rather than `N`.
6. This would be **much** easier using `scipy.io.wavfile` if you can.  I will assume for now that you can't, though.
7. Although `wave` has a link to the `struct` module, it is, as far as I can tell, undocumented.  Even if it was documented, it would be clearer to use the `struct` module directly.
8. You potentially re-use the same `struct` value many times.  It would probably be easier and quicker to define it once and re-use it.
9. Along similar lines, you write the same value multiple times.  Since it is just a `bytes` object, it would probably be easier and cleaner to just duplicate the value.  They are small enough that this shouldn't be a problem.
10. You use `i` for two different things in the same loop.  Don't do that.  You should use a more informative name for the first `i`.
11. You only use a small bit of the `i` variable.  You should probably strip that off at the beginning.
12. Rather than finding a particular value in `i` and then slicing to that, you can just use `i.partition('(')` to split it at the first `'('`, then take the first value returned using `i.partition('(')[0]`.
13. You don't even want the `key`, you want the frame, or rather the frequency.
14. You create variables only to immediately re-name them, then never use the original name.  This doesn't have much effect on performance, but it is confusing.
15. I don't know what `my_code` produces, but I will assume for my improvement it is an iterable.  If it isn't, then just put the `list()` wrapper you have now back in.
16. Is `Syntax.struc.num` a numpy array?  If it is, then change `freqs = np.array([Syntax.struc.num[key] if key else 0 for key in keys])` to `freqs = Syntax.struc.num[keys]`.
17. If Syntax.struc.num is already numeric, then you can drop the `freqs = freqs.astype(np.float)`.
18. If you define your frequencies in a numpy array at the beginning, you can also pre-calculate `period` and `omega` much faster in a single step rather than at every point in the loop.
19. Try to avoid "magic numbers", which are seemingly-arbitrary numbers in your code.  They should be named variables for clarity.
20. You never use `duration` or `samples`.
21. Numpy has a `tobytes` method that converts an array directly into binary.
22. You create `ssignal`, but then write `signal` instead.  If you can just write numbers, you don't need `ssignal` at all, right?
23. I think it would be easier to read in the future if you use the `music.set*` functions rather than setting everything in one big function.
24. Are you sure you want the max value to be `16384`? 16 bit wave files can handle `32760`.

So this is how I would structure your code, assuming you are not able or not willing to use `scipy`.

```
import struct
import wave

import numpy as np

import out


def compiler():
    print("Loaded out.py")
    print("Compiling...")
    lst = my_code(out.code)
    keys = (int(ilst.partition('(')[0]) for ilst in lst)
    freqs = np.array([Syntax.struc.num[key] if key else -1 for key in keys])
    freqs = freqs.astype(np.float)
    periods = FREQ/freqs
    omegas = np.pi * 2 / period
    periods = np.floor(periods)
    print("Compiled!")
    print("Linking...")

    print("Bytes len: {0} = {0} ".format(len(periods), BLEN*len(periods)))

    packed_value = np.zeros(100, dtype=np.int16).tobytes()

    maxamp = 2**14
    maxlen = 400
    nchan = 2
    sampwidth = 1
    nframes = 0

    with wave.open('out.wav', 'w') as music:
        music.setnchannels(nchan)
        music.setsampwidth(sampwidth)
        music.setframerate(FREQ)

        for period, omega in zip(periods, omegas):
            if period < 0:
                music.writeframes(packed_value)
                continue

            signal = maxamp * np.sin(np.arange(period)*omega).
            signal = np.resize(signal, maxlen)  # duplicate up to the correct length
            signal = signal.astype(np.int16).tobytes()  # transform to binary

            music.writeframes(signal)

print("Linked to out.wav!")
```

Comment: According to PEP 8, you should use [all caps for constants](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#constants); there is no special naming convention for global variables.

Comment: Sorry, you are right.  I meant module-level constants.  Fixed.

Comment: Thanks. I did not know that scipy has a wave module

Comment: I made some minor fixups to the code.  Please see the edit history.